# Why does it look like ffmpeg is limiting the encode speed

Tags: video, ffmpeg, scale, video-encoding

### **Objective**

I'm trying to create lower resolutions videos with the max possible speed, so I'm using cuda to do it

My command:

```
ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -extra_hw_frames 10 -i input.mp4 -vf scale_cuda=-2:720 -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -preset fast -b:v 5M output.mp4
```

### Problem

This command reached a speed of 33x on a GTX 1650 and I couldn't make it go faster, so I asked my friend with a RTX 3070 (which has much more CUDA cores) and the max speed was the same 33x

### Question

**Is FFmpeg actually limiting the encode speed? And exist a way to make it go faster?**

Comment: Your bottleneck could be your storage device. Are `input.mp4` and `output.mp4` placed on your fasted storage device? (NVMe > SSD > HDD)

Comment: Also, FYI, NVENC is a separate circuitry from CUDA cores [see this](https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/nvenc-application-note/). So, having more CUDA core wouldn't help the transcoding speed. (Clock difference however would help I presume)

Comment: @kesh Yes, both are in NVMe. So how I properly use my CUDA cores for max speed?

Comment: Run `ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_nvenc` to get the list of all presets. I'd try `-preset p1` to see if it's faster than `fast` that you are currently using. Another is to see if removing `-b:v` or pick even larger value makes any difference.

Comment: @kesh I've already tried changing the preset to all available and other bitrate values (also removing it) and remains at 32-33x

Comment: That's probably as fast as it goes then. How much does it speed up (or down) if you don't scale? (just curious)

Comment: @kesh without the scale filter stay at the same speed as well :(